# How can I prove `add_le_cases` (`forall n m p q, n + m <= p + q -> n <= p \/ m <= q`)

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I am trying to complete the series of exercises `le_exercises` from [Logical Foundations' chapter on inductive propositions](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/IndProp.html).

This series is mostly based on the inductive relation `le`, defined thusly:

```
Inductive le : nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | le_n (n : nat)                : le n n
  | le_S (n m : nat) (H : le n m) : le n (S m).

Notation "n <= m" := (le n m).
```

The particular theorem I am stuck at is the following:

```
Theorem add_le_cases : forall n m p q,
  n + m <= p + q -> n <= p \/ m <= q.
```

The previous theorems in these series that I managed to prove so far are:

```
Lemma le_trans : ∀ m n o, m ≤ n → n ≤ o → m ≤ o.

Theorem O_le_n : ∀ n, 0 ≤ n.

Theorem n_le_m__Sn_le_Sm : ∀ n m, n ≤ m → S n ≤ S m.

Theorem Sn_le_Sm__n_le_m : ∀ n m, S n ≤ S m → n ≤ m.

Theorem lt_ge_cases : ∀ n m, n < m ∨ n ≥ m.

Theorem le_plus_l : ∀ a b, a ≤ a + b.

Theorem plus_le : ∀ n1 n2 m, n1 + n2 ≤ m → n1 ≤ m ∧ n2 ≤ m.
```

The book gives a hint stating that the theorem `add_le_cases` may be "easier to prove by induction on `n`" which I tried in various ways, but can't seem to go anywhere.

```
Theorem add_le_cases : forall n m p q,
  n + m <= p + q -> n <= p \/ m <= q.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n.
  - intros. left. apply O_le_n.
  - intros. inversion H.
    + destruct m.
      * right. apply O_le_n.
      *  (* stuck *)
```

I have considered using the `plus_le` theorem but can't seem to get anything useful from it. I feel there must be something crucial missing from my understanding but you can't know what you don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I would not do `inversion H` and `destruct m`. I would just `destruct p` and after solving the `O` case, then massage `H` a bit to be able to apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you! I had noticed that `H` could be rewritten so that the induction hypothesis could be applied to it, but because I wasn't `destruct`ing the right term I couldn't leverage this fact.